# Почему сочетание «как по писаному» иногда пишут неправильно?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис, нн, н

Можно обратить внимание на то, что в текстах из Нацкорпуса встречаются четыре формы записи: (1) ***как по писаному*** (78 примеров), (2) ***как по писанному*** (18 примеров), (3) ***как по-писаному*** (38 примеров),  (4) ***как по-писанному*** (14 примеров).

Только **неграмотностью** это сложно объяснить. Норма  ***«по писаному»*** не новая, она обозначена уже в словаре Ушакова. Для сравнения: в XIX веке (Даль, Михельсон) писали ***«как по писанному».***

Насколько часто используется дефисное написание **наречия** из современного толкового словаря (не умеет по-писаному)?

**Приложение**

**Гоголь Н.В.** (1809 — 1852)

Произнесенное метко, все равно что ***писанное***, не вырубливается топором. Вы, Иван Никифорович, разносились так с своим ружьем, как дурень с ***писаною*** торбою, — сказал Иван Иванович с досадою, потому что действительно начинал уже сердиться.

**Из словаря Даля:**

Врет, как ***по писанному***. Неграмотный, а пряники ест ***писаные***. Глядит, что корова на ***писаные*** ворота!

Comment: М-м... Умеете Вы озадачить, закрутить.

Comment: Можно объяснить отсутствием доступа к источникам. Интернет относительно недавно появился.